# Test if Tree contains Object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need a function to check if an object exists in a tree.

I recursively run through the tree and use lodash to check for equality of objects:

```js
var objectInResultList = function (obj, list) {
  list.forEach(function (item) {
    if (_.isEqual(item, obj) === true) {
      return true
    }
    else if (item.children.length > 0) {
      return objectInResultList(obj, item.children);
    }
  });
  return false;
};
          
var item = {"name":"Enterprise1.1","description": "testTest","children":[]};
    
var resultList = [{"name":"Enterprise1.1","description": "testTest","children":[{"name":"Enterprise1.1","description": "testTest","children":[]}]}];
    
var ret = objectInResultList(item, resultList);
alert(ret);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.2.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The function should return `true` if the item is in the list and otherwise return `false`, but currently it always returns `false`.

Can someone find my problem?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jonashans91/nw15hkm9/)

Comment: What is the problem you've faced with this code? What is the result you get instead of the expected?

Comment: my function should return true if item is in resultlist ... and return false if is not in the resultlist

Comment: And what you're getting with your current code?

Comment: I get false ... 
but it should return true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a couple of things.

1. A minor thing - your predicate is not returning `false` if the objects don't match and it has no children.
2. You are returning `true/false` from the predicate, but aren't using it anywhere so `objectInResultList` always returns false.

Rather than using `forEach`, it is easier to use [`find`](https://lodash.com/docs#find) or [`findIndex`](https://lodash.com/docs#findIndex), and the use the result of that to determine what to return from `objectInResultList`. For example if `find` returns `undefined` because of no match, then you return `false`.

In this case, you are using a tree with multiple lists, so using `find` makes more sense than `findIndex`.

```js
var objectInResultList = function (obj, list) {
  // call find to get the matching object
  var match = list.find(function (item) {
    if (_.isEqual(item, obj) === true) {
      return true;
    }
    else if (item.children.length > 0) {
      return objectInResultList(obj, item.children);
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  
  // if match is undefined return false. If we found a match, return true
  return !_.isUndefined(match);
};

var item = {"name":"Enterprise1.1","description": "testTest","children":[]};

var resultList = [{"name":"Enterprise1.1","description": "testTest","children":[{"name":"Enterprise1.1","description": "testTest","children":[]}]}];

var ret = objectInResultList(item, resultList);
alert(ret);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.2.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach() has no return-value and it ignores any returned value. So returning true or false in the search-function is useless.

You should use a better iterator-function.

```
var objectInResultList = function (obj, list) {
    function search(item){
        if(item == null) return false;
        if(_.isArray(item)) return _.some(item, search);
        if(_.isEqual(item, obj)) return true;
        return search(item.children);
    }
    return search(list);
};
```